# is there any inbuilt function for image recognition

Tags: java, iphone, android, image-processing

i want to use a function for image recognition 
i dont want to make an algorithm.
please suggest me a function where i could compare two images and tell whether these images belong to the same object. 
please help me!.

Comment: `i dont want to make an algorithm` maybe you shouldn't be programming then

Answer (score 2):

Arbitrary image recognition is something that computers can't yet do (even for supercomputers). However, [Google Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggles/#text) comes close, being able to recognize a wide range of objects. Read its limitations, and see if it suits your purpose.

Comment: Not only that, but also *human beings* couldn't reliably compare two images and tell whether they "belong to the same object" or not, at least not without extensive training in what that means, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are definitely ways to do this but they all depend on what you are trying to do. If you are more specific about what you want to compare then it will be easier to give a more thorough answer.

There are some excellent libraries out there but it will require some effort on your part to learn and understand how to use them and how to use them on the iPhone.

The most famous algorithms so assist in finding images inside other images are called SIFT and SURF. Unfortunately both are patented and cannot be used commercially in an application.

Consider using OpenCV for most of your image operations.
Or you could use OpenFrameworks (google has tagged it as a phishing site for some reason, im sure theyll fix that soon)
You might also consider VXL which has started to become more popular.

Good luck!